# Screen Scraping Error while using NSURL - Objective c

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection, screen-scraping, nsurl

I am currently trying to write a program that reads the source code of http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=aapl and returns the value associated with the average 3 month volume (Avg Vol 3m). I am using NSURL as follows:

```
NSString *Ticker = @"aaple";
NSString *website = @"http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=";
NSString *newwebsite = [website stringByAppendingString: Ticker];
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString: newwebsite];
NSString *myHomePage = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL: myURL encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding error: NULL];
NSLog (@"%@", myHomePage);
```

However when I print out the source code I notice that the string does not contain the value of the average 3 month volume nor does it contain the reference to it. Similarly I notice that the output of the code is different from the source code of the same website when viewed through a browser (view->developer->view source on chrome). Am I using the correct classes/methods? What can I do so that my program's output is the same as that viewed through my browser?

Btw I am aware that once I have the proper source code I can extract the needed strings using rangeofString, substringToIndex, subStringFromIndex, etc. The focus of this question is how to obtain the correct source code and not what to do to it once I have it.

Comment: It is possibly loaded after the page loaded. this often happens for dynamic contents.

Comment: So how do I change it so that it loads before the page is loaded?

Comment: Maybe NSURLRequest is more suited

Comment: How would I fix this code so that it implements NSURLRequest accurately. Any help would be appreciated since I am an objective-c n00b.